# My component scan on Spring 5.3.18 does not work

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

I have little problem with spring ComponentScan in my application.

Here is my Test spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dhl.cdm","com.dhl.common.dao"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScript("cdm_schema.sql");
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean(name="jdbcTemplateUserRepository")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateUserRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean result = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        result.setDataSource(dataSource());
        result.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.dhl.cdm", "com.dhl.common.entity" });

        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        result.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager man = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        man.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return man;
    }
    @Bean
    public CdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader getCdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader() {
       return new MockCdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader();
    }

}
```

When I tried to run test on this configuration, it fails with :

```
17:55:42.882 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@675230cd] to prepare test instance [com.dhl.cdm.core.entityconfig.entity.referencePath.ReferencePathParserTest@2a73a64f]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.dhl.cdm.core.entityconfig.entity.referencePath.ReferencePathParserTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityConfigProviderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dhl.cdm.core.entityconfig.service.EntityConfigProviderService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

But I have missing class on my classpath :

```
package com.dhl.cdm.core.entityconfig.service;

import com.dhl.cdm.core.entityconfig.entity.configWrapper.EntityConfigWrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
@Transactional
@Profile("!autodiscovery")
public class EntityConfigProviderServiceImpl implements EntityConfigProviderService {

    private Map<String, EntityConfigWrapper> entityConfigWrapperMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private IEntityConfigLoader loader;

    @Override
    public EntityConfigWrapper getEntityConfigWrapper(String entityId) {
        if (entityConfigWrapperMap.isEmpty()) {
            entityConfigWrapperMap.putAll(loader.loadEntityConfig());
        }
        return entityConfigWrapperMap.get(entityId);
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        entityConfigWrapperMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public List<EntityConfigWrapper> getAll() {
        if (entityConfigWrapperMap.isEmpty()) {
            entityConfigWrapperMap.putAll(loader.loadEntityConfig());
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(entityConfigWrapperMap.values());
    }

}
```

Can someone give me a point why component scan in Spring does not working? Maybe there is some different between test classpath and normal classpath, I dont know. Thanks for help.

Full stacktrace for example:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryCdmDataProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expres
sed through field 'loader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dhl.cdm.core.confi
gProvider.pojo.dao.CdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.spr
ingframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:659)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:639)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:656)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dhl.cdm.core.configProvider.pojo.dao.CdmInMemoryConfigu
rationDataLoader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation
.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:656)
        ... 65 more

getTitle(com.dhl.cdm.core.localization.LocalizationServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) 
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) 
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'menuInMemoryDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'provider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryCdmDataProvi
der': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying b
ean of type 'com.dhl.cdm.core.configProvider.pojo.dao.CdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:659)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:639)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)       
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryCdmDataProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expres
sed through field 'loader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dhl.cdm.core.confi
gProvider.pojo.dao.CdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.spr
ingframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:659)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:639)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:656)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dhl.cdm.core.configProvider.pojo.dao.CdmInMemoryConfigu
rationDataLoader' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation
.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:656)
        ... 65 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is reporting that no qualifying bean is available: it does not mean that the class is not in the classpath, but that a bean, implementing that interface, is not included in the Spring context.

One possible reason of the problem is that you are, in some way, in some place, enabling the `autodiscovery` Spring profile, and you indicated in your service that the bean must be only defined when that profile is not active:

```java
@Profile("!autodiscovery")
```

Please, double check that: Spring outputs the active Spring profiles when it starts the context, and adjust the profiles for your test as appropiate.

Please, consider review carefully the full error stacktrace for nested error that could motivate the problem.

Comment: I tryed to remove @Profile annotation and It unfortunatelly doesnt work :-(

Comment: Hi @PetrKostroun. Thank you very much for trying the suggested approach and for the feedback. I see... Please, could you provide in your answer the full error stacktrace? As I said, perhaps a transitive dependency could be the cause of the issue. Is that the only test that do not run successfully? Is it a general problem? How are you actually running your tests?

Comment: I provide full stack trace in my question.

Comment: Thank you very much @PetrKostroun. It looks like the bean that is causing the issue is `com.dhl.cdm.core.configProvider.pojo.dao.CdmInMemoryConfigu
rationDataLoader`, required by `inMemoryCdmDataProvider` and the `loader` field (perhaps you are taking about  the `loader` field in`EntityConfigProviderServiceImpl`?). The `CdmInMemoryConfigu
rationDataLoader` bean seems to be defined in your `TestConfiguration` as a mock, is that correct? Is your `TestConfiguration` correctly picked by Spring?

Comment: It seems that component scan doesnt work, becouse MockCdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader is currently presented in test classes as @Service component, but Spring cannot load it a bean. The configuration of MockCdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader in TestConfiguration is absolate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @PetrKostroun. Yes, certainly it can be the cause. Are your `TestConfiguration` beans included in the Spring context successfully? Is `MockCdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader` the only class that is not working properly? Please, could you provide an updated version of your code in the answer? At least, could you provide a snippet of the source code of `MockCdmInMemoryConfigurationDataLoader`?

Comment: @PetrKostroun If your classes are not being loaded by Spring is possible, as you said, that component scan is not working properly. You seem to be using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner `. Do you included the appropriate context configuration in your test? I mean, for instance, assuming that `TestConfiguration` contains the necessary bean definitions and `@ComponentScan` annotation: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)`.

Comment: No, I tryed to click the class in Intelijj Idea, and Component class is required packages, but maven cant load this packages. When I run it into intellij Idea, It runs smootly, co problem is in maven build.

Comment: And Petr, how do you run your tests with maven? Just `mvn test`? Please, could you include the relevant sections of the `pom.xml` in your answer?

Comment: I run simply mvn clean istall.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @PetrKostroun. Probably, in Intellij, you are activating some kind of profile/s, and this profile/s are not being activated when you run your tests with maven. Please, review your test run configuration in Intellij, and search for any Spring profile specific configuration. And try to see if the same profiles are active when you run Maven. Sorry, but without your pom.xml and without any clue about your Intellij configuration it is very difficult to say where the problem could be.

Comment: my pom.xml is in https://pastebin.com/swWb3gQD . Thanks for help

Comment: And I try to remove @profile from my services to avoid profile issue, but without effect.